# std::bad_alloc Am I allocating too much memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a programming assignment where I have to create a struct that has an array (sized 20) of integers defined by these functions:

1. f(0)=2700
2. f(n+1)=2*f(n)

The struct all has a char * [] (sized 20) where each element is allocated memory which is sized according to the value in the integer array. So the larger the index, the more memory is allocated.

I do this allocation in a loop. bns is an object of my struct with the integer array, bigNums; and the char * [] as bigLettersArray. Here is the code (minified):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

struct BigNumsStruct {
    int bigNums[20];
    char* bigLettersArray[20];
};
int main()
{
    BigNumsStruct bns;
    bns.bigNums[0] = 2700;
    bns.bigLettersArray[0] = new char[2700];
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        bns.bigNums[i] = 2 * bns.bigNums[i - 1];
        bns.bigLettersArray[i] = new char[bns.bigNums[i]];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine until i=18, then the memory allocation is too much (presumably). I am trying to get it to run on my Windows 10 machine. The code was running fine on my Mac and my virtualized Linux machines.

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers and `new` at all? Any good and substantial reasoning to do so?

Comment: because my professor wants us to

Comment: That's not what I'd take as a _substantial reasoning_.

Comment: The purpose of the assignment is to review pointers and dynamic memory allocation. There is no other reason beyond that.

Comment: Well, as for your question: That can likely happen if you have for instance uninitialized values in `bns.bigNums[i]` for instance. But there can be many other reasons also. Post a [MCVE] please that reproduces the problem please. From that snippet no one can really tell you what's going wrong. Its all left to wild speculations.

Comment: Is your Windows 32-bit? If so, you are overflowing memory and cannot easily get around that.

Comment: TheDude if you're suggesting he lead an insurrection against his professor and fail his class, I'd say your reasoning isn't all that substantial either.

Comment: @TheDude I posted a minimal example

Comment: @KenY-N It is 64-bit

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I don't care about incompetent professors. In fact I'm quite annoyed by them. Tax waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2^20 is 1000000 give or take.  *2700 is about 3 billion.

On a 32 bit system there is not enough address space for that.  On a 64 bit system it may require a lot of virtual memory.  Both could lead to a bad alloc.

Or in short yes.

I would be surprised at a bad alloc at ~1 gig on a 64 bit system however.  You are probably compiling a 32 bit exe.